# Offload Unused Apps - Apps incorrectly labeled as Never Used

Tags: ios, storage

I’m running iOS 11.3. Recently I activated **Offload Unused Apps** in order to free up space. That is supposed to work by examining the date each app is last used, and offloading the ones you don’t use often. The problem is, my iPhone doesn’t seem to be tracking that “last used” date properly.

As the screenshot shows, when I go to `Settings app → General → iPhone Storage`, all the apps say **Never Used**, instead of displaying the last usage date.

[image]

This isn’t just a cosmetic thing; it is actually affecting the behaviour of Offload Unused Apps. I’ve had apps that I use frequently, such as my banking app and Google Docs, offloaded.

Can someone tell me how to get the correct Last Used dates to be tracked?  I’ve checked that `Settings → Privacy → Share iPhone Analytics` is turned ON, but that doesn’t seem to fix it.